# Using URL to highlight a table row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a database. When I type `.../array.php?id=1` into the url, it will highlight that row. If I put `id=2` in, then it will highlight row 2.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
function connect(){
  // Make a MySQL Connection
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "school") or die(mysqli_error());
  return $link;
}

if ($_GET)
{
  if(isset($_GET["id"])) $id = $_GET["id"]; 
}


// select query 
$query = "SELECT * FROM graden" ;

if (isset($id)) { $query.= " WHERE id = $id "; }

$result = mysqli_query(connect(),$query);   

// table making
$table = "<table border='1'>";
$table .= "<tr>
             <th> ID </th>
             <th>Graden Celcius</th> 
             <th>Aanduiding</th>
             <th>Image</th> 
        </tr>";

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "Image") {
            $table .="<td><img src='$value' /></td>"; 
        } elseif ($key == "temp") {
            $table .="<td><a href='array.php?id=$value'>$value</a></td>"; 
        } else {
            $table .="<td>$value</td>";         
        }

    }
    $table .= "</tr>";
}

$table .="</table>";

echo $table;
?>
```

Comment: There is an issue that needs to be fixed before you can implement the functionality you described: you are not creating table rows (`<tr>`) for the rows. You will need to create a new `<tr>` inside the `foreach()` loop. Then to add the highlight, maintain a counter, and if the counter matches the value of `$_GET['id']` add an appropriate CSS class to the row.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't see a question either.

Comment: I have a table in a database and my question is how can I create it ... that when I type .../array.php?id=1 into the url, it will highlight that row. If I put id=2 in, then it will highlight row 2

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably something similar to this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    $table .="<tr ".($_GET["id"] == $row["id"]?" style='background-color:yellow'":"").">";
    foreach ($row as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($key == "Image")
        {
            $table .="<td><img src='$value' /></td>"; 
        }
        elseif ($key == "temp")
        {
            $table .="<td><a href='array.php?id=$value'>$value</a></td>"; 
        }
        else
        {
            $table .="<td>$value</td>";         
        }
    }
    $table .= "</tr>";
}
```

This uses a ternary if to conditionally set the style attribute for the table based on if the row's id matches the supplied query parameter.

Comment: when I try using this i get a error on that line  $table .='<tr ".($_GET["id"] == $row["id"]?" style='background-color:yellow':"").">';

Comment: o yes i see it thank you. I then get Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\periode4\graden\array.php on line 39

Comment: substitute id for whatever field you are matching against in your database. I assumed id was part of your result set

Answer (score 0):

If you add the ID criteria to your query with

```
if (isset($id)) $query.= " WHERE id = $id ";
```

then you'll have only that one row in your table. So if you do not want to filter, but rather to highlight that row, I recommend not to put the ID in the query, but check the equality for it inside your loop where you print table rows, and if the row has the corresponding ID, color it for example.
Also, you've missed the TR tags from the rows.
Your highlighting code could be something like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
    $table .= '<tr';
    if ($row['id'] === $id)
        $table .= 'style="background-color: #ff4444;"';
    $table .= '>';
    // rest of your code ....
}
```